# How to create FTP account in nopCommerce Admin Panel?

Tags: web, database-backups, nopcommerce, remote-backup

I am new in nopCommerce. I need to download my website from server using nopCommerce admin panel.

As i go through the different forums and come to know, that i have to create some FTP account and then i ll be able to download the full backup of my website.

Besides this there is another issue then how can i get the DB backup. kindly guide me in right direction to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you would do through your web host's control panel, not within NopCommerce.